# How to get response value outside of axios function in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am calling an API and getting the response properly but same response value is showing empty outside the response function. I need to get it from outside while page onload.Code below

### Test.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect,useRef, useMemo  } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';  
function Test() {
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`)  
      .then(res => {  
        setState(res.data);  
      })  
      console.log(state)
    },
        []);
}
export default Test;
```

Comment: I don't know what you were expecting here. Could be https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/3001761, or just a basic https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3001761.

Comment: I just need the response value outside of function , but as per above code it is showing empty

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to console the value outside of useEffect like this:

> 

```
import React, { useState, useEffect,useRef, useMemo  } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';  
function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`)  
      .then(res => {  
        // console.log(res.data)
        setState(res.data);  
      })  
    },[]);
    console.log(state)
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Not working ,showing empty value

Answer (score 0):

`useState` takes one render to change so if you read the `state` right after `setState` then you will always read ***previous value*** not ***updated value***.
For using the value instantly you should save the `response` in local variable.Like this

```
 useEffect(() => {
let response ="";
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`)  
      .then(res => {  
response= res.data        
setState(res.data);  
      })  
      console.log(response)
    },
```

Comment: Not working ,showing empty

Comment: can you console `res.data` and send snap here

Answer (score 0):

It won't change the state immediately, because they create queues to optimize performance. You can check the data being loaded in the div tags.

```
const Test = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").then((result) => {
      setState(result.data);
    });
  }, []);

  if(state){
    return <div>{state.title}</div> 
  }

  return <div></div>;
};

export default Test;
```

For more information refer [useState do not update immediately](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-hooks-cheat-sheet-solutions-common-problems/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20find%20that%20useState,changes%20don%27t%20update%20immediately.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there any alternate way to fix this?